# On line 58, i keep getting the message "missing \item"

Tags: errors

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\pagestyle{empty}
\oddsidemargin=0pt
\topmargin=0pt
\textwidth=6.5in
\textheight=8.5in
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\large{\LaTeX\ Example 4}
\end{center}
Symbols of inclusion in \LaTeX\ can be scaled to match the complexity of the expression.  For
example, consider
\[
(\frac{x^2+1}{x^2+x+1})(x^3+x^2-3x+1)
\]
\begin{quote}
\begin{verbatim}
\[
(\frac{x^2+1}{x^2+x+1})(x^3+x^2-3x+1)
\]
\end{verbatim}
\end{quote}
The parenthesis don't quite match the size of the fraction.  This can be fixed with the \verb+\+left\verb+(+
and the \verb+\+right\verb+)+ commands:
\[
\left(\frac{x^2+1}{x^2+x+1}\right)(x^3+x2-3x+1)
\]
\begin{quote}
\begin{verbatim}
\[
\left(\frac{x^2+1}{x^2+x+1}\right)(x^3+x2-3x+1)
\]
\end{verbatim}
\end{quote}
Or, with braces:
\[
\left\{\frac{x^2+1}{x^2+x+1}\right\}(x^3+x^2-3x+1)
\]
\begin{quote}
\begin{verbatim}
\[
\left\{\frac{x^2+1}{x^2+x+1}\right\}(x^3+x^2-3x+1)
\]
\end{verbatim}
\end{quote}
Observations:
\begin{itemize}
\item Notice in the last example that the braces are each preceded by a backslash.  This is 
to let \LaTeX\ know that the braces are to be typeset and do not define a new scope.
\item The \verb+\+left and \verb+\+right commands must match up in pairs, although the symbols of
inclusion do not have to match.  For example \verb+\+left\verb+(+ can be closed by \verb+\+right\verb+)+.
\item The symbols of inclusion \verb+[.]+ and \verb+|.|+ handled similarly.
\item \verb+\+left. and \verb+\+right. are special symbols of inclusion that are ``empty.``  They are not
typeset, but are used to maintain the \verb+\+left and \verb+\+right match that is required by
\LaTeX\.
\item Notice \verb+\+frac \verb+{+ a\verb+}{+ b\verb+}+ typsets the fractions \frac{a}{b}.
\end{itemize}
---Britney Wiggins
\end{document}
```

Comment: It is better to use `\usepackage[<options>]{geometry}` instead of `\topmargin`, `\textwidth`, etc when specify the paper size, margin, text width, etc. Read the manual by invoking `texdoc geometry` from your terminal.

Comment: Off-topic comment: You seem to be using the `\verb+...+` instructions mainly to "escape" the backslash character (\ ). If that's the purpose, you may be better off using `\textbackslash` -- doing so will render the backslash character in the font that's used in the surrounding stuff. On the other hand, if you want to use `\verb+...+` as a means for typesetting LaTeX code in a monospaced font (a common practice!), you could write `\verb+\frac{a}{b}+` instead of `\verb+\+frac \verb+{+ a\verb+}{+ b\verb+}+` -- much easier to read and debug, right?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Two things:

1. Don't end your sentences with `\.` (line 57).
2. `\frac` works in math mode, so use `$\frac{a}{b}$` (line 58).